# How to access property of an object which belongs to another function inside a function using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on **Tic Tac Toe** game using jQuery. I am almost done but stuck at point. How can I add code to the end of the `squareClicked` function to check to see if there is a winner? If there is, I want to assign `bgreen` class to only squares(tds).

```
$('table').on('click', squareClicked);

function squareClicked(e) {
    var $sqr = $(e.target);
    var player = $('.current-player').attr('id');
    if (!$sqr.attr('class')) {
        $sqr.addClass(player + '-marker');
        switchPlayer();
    }
}

function getBoard() {
    var board = [];
    $('td').each(function () {
        board.push(this.className[0]);
    });
    return board;
}

function checkWin() {
    var board = getBoard();
    // array of possible win sets
    var winArray = [
        [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]];
    var winInfo = {
        win: false
    };
    // loop through the possible win sets
    for (var i = 0; i < winArray.length; i++) {
        // get the marks at the three win locations
        a = board[winArray[i][0]];
        b = board[winArray[i][1]];
        c = board[winArray[i][2]];
        // see if the same marker is at each location
        if (a && a === b && b === c) {
            winInfo.win = true;
            winInfo.play = winArray[i];
            winInfo.winner = a;
            return winInfo;
        }
    }
    return winInfo;
}
```

**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbhkk92L/)**

I called `checkWin();` inside the `squareClicked` function but it doesn't run at all.

Comment: Could you show us how you called checkWin()? Perhaps a JSFiddle would help.

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't run at all". Do you get any error message? Is checkWin() defined on the global object?

Comment: Thanks.  Okay, so think about what the return value of checkWin is: an object with properties win, play and winner; I'm assuming at the end of squareClicked, you want to call it and assign its value to a variable; then check the win property for truthiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice checkWin() returns an object with 3 properties: win, play and winner; Assign the result to a variable and then check the truthiness of win in order to determine if the player just won.

```
function squareClicked(e) {
    var $sqr = $(e.target);
    var player = $('.current-player').attr('id');
    if (!$sqr.attr('class')) {
        $sqr.addClass(player + '-marker');
        switchPlayer();
    }
    var winInfo = checkWin();
    if (winInfo.win) {
        console.log("You won!");
        // do win stuff  here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function squareClicked(e) {
    var $sqr = $(e.target);
    var player = $('.current-player').attr('id');
    if (!$sqr.attr('class')) {
        $sqr.addClass(player + '-marker');
        switchPlayer();
    }
    var result = checkWin();
    if (result.win){
       // do something here ...
    }
}
```